# Which lifecycle method will be called when the app goes "Recent Apps" in android in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    setState(() {
      shouldBlur = state == AppLifecycleState.inactive ||
          state == AppLifecycleState.paused;
    });
  }
```

I don't get a call when the app goes recent list but It is getting called when the app is fully minimised in `Android 12`